# Position relative, float takes div out of the normal flow

Tags: css, css-position

How can i prevent taking div out of the normal flow but still using float, like this:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#one {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#two {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Now div "one" has no height and div "two" just looks like it isn't in the first div.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ahh, the collapse problem.  There's an excellant article about floats here http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
In your case, I'd add

```
overflow: auto
```

to `#one`

The relative info is quoted below:

> Techniques for Clearing Floats
>
> If you are in a situation where you always know what the succeeding
>   element is going to be, you can apply the clear: both; value to that
>   element and go about your business. This is ideal as it requires no
>   fancy hacks and no additional elements making it perfectly semantic.
>   Of course things don't typically work out that way and we need to have
>   more float-clearing tools in our toolbox.
>
> **The Empty Div Method** is, quite literally, an empty div. `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`. Sometimes you'll see a `<br />` element
>   or some other random element used, but div is the most common because
>   it has no brower default styling, doesn't have any special function,
>   and is unlikely to be generically styled with CSS. This method is
>   scorned by semantic purists since its presence has no contexual
>   meaning at all to the page and is there purely for presentation. Of
>   course in the strictest sense they are right, but it gets the job done
>   right and doesn't hurt anybody.
>
> **The Overflow Method** relies on setting the overflow CSS property on a parent element. If this property is set to auto or hidden on the
>   parent element, the parent will expand to contain the floats,
>   effectively clearing it for succeeding elements. This method can be
>   beautifully semantic as it may not require an additional elements.
>   However if you find yourself adding a new div just to apply this, it
>   is equally as unsemantic as the empty div method and less adaptable.
>   Also bear in mind that the overflow property isn't specifically for
>   clearing floats. Be careful not to hide content or trigger unwanted
>   scrollbars.
>
> **The Easy Clearing Method** uses a clever CSS pseudo selector `(:after)` to clear floats. Rather than setting the overflow on the
>   parent, you apply an additional class like "clearfix" to it. Then
>   apply this CSS:
>
> ```
> .clearfix:after { 
>    content: "."; 
>    visibility: hidden; 
>    display: block; 
>    height: 0; 
>    clear: both;
> }
> ```
>
> This will apply a small bit of content, hidden from view, after the
>   parent element which clears the float. This isn't quite the whole
>   story, as additional code needs to be used to accomodate for older
>   browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing your dive #one collapse. Adding an overflow value to the CSS for that element should fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. Try adding it to both DIVs:

**For the sake of testing, you might want to add some background color.

[**jsFiddle example here!**](http://jsfiddle.net/QTWnC/)

```
position: relative;
float: left;
clear: none;
display: block;
```