# Effect of overflow and clear styles with floats

Tags: css, css-float

I'm pretty CSS-savvy, but I'm seeing some odd float/clear behavior. I have it working, but I'm not entirely sure why and am looking for an explanation.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ismyrnow/JV5n6/

[image: Screenshot from JSFiddle]

I have a 2 column layout - sidebar and content - where the sidebar is floated but the content is not; the content div has a left margin applied to it.

If I use `clear:both` on any elements in the content div, the element unexpectedly drops below the height of the sidebar div (unexpectedly because the floated sidebar isn't directly affecting the positioning of items inside the content area).

What is even more unexpected, is that when I add `overflow:auto` to the content div, the problem goes away. (I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907063/192217))

Can someone explain:

1. Why `clear:both` would cause an element to clear a floated element that isn't directly affecting its position.
2. Why `overflow:auto` on the parent element fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > Why `clear:both` would cause an element to clear a floated element that isn't directly affecting its position.

   It may not be directly affecting its position, but it would still have affected it anyway, because in the absence of any clearance, floats aren't normally restricted in how they affect the rest of the normal flow layout even once they are taken out of it, not even by different parent elements such as your `.b` content element with the left margin in this case. The only real restriction is that floating elements may only affect elements that come after them in document tree order, i.e. elements that are following (not preceding) siblings, as well as their descendants.

   The content that's just above the element within your content column isn't tall enough to push it beneath the floated element. If you remove that declaration, you would see that [both `.c` elements become positioned next to their respective floats as well](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/JV5n6/2).

   When you add `clear`, what happens is that it forces the clearing element to be positioned beneath the float regardless of where it ends up horizontally.
2. > Why `overflow:auto` on the parent element fixes the issue.

   This is because any block boxes with `overflow` other than `visible` generate [block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). A property of a block formatting context is that floating boxes outside it can never interact with any boxes inside it, and vice versa.

   Once you cause the content element to establish its own block formatting context, your floating element is no longer able to affect any elements inside the content element (see the section on the [`float` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position)), *and* the clearing element inside it is no longer able to clear any floats that are outside the content element (see the [`clear` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control)).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't known about "block formatting contexts" before, and your link to the CSS spec explained it perfectly.

Comment: Do you have a reference for where you say floats affect "descendants of following siblings"?

Comment: @Ishmael Smyrnow: The spec does not say it explicitly, but because following siblings are considered to be later in source order, then it follows that their descendants must also be later, and not earlier or equal, in source order.

Answer (score 1):

For `clear:both`

The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur.

When applied to floating elements, it moves the margin edge of the element below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This affects the position of later floats, since later floats cannot be positioned higher than earlier ones.

The floats that are relevant to be cleared are the earlier floats within the same block formatting context.

I hope this will clear your doubt.
This is the link from where i found the above info.....

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: Avoid `link-only` answers, these answers will **become invalid once the link got broken**. Include relevant code snippets here and use links for reference only

Comment: okay, thanks i'll edit that..., but that link is mozila's developer, i don't think they will take down that link easily....

Comment: What confuses me is what is included in "all relevant floats" (third paragraph). I wouldn't consider that float "relevant". I assume the CSS spec has a clearer definition of what that means, but it's not yet clear to me why it's relevant.